# Area of cylinder cut out by parabolic cylinder

Tags: integration

Find the surface area of $y^2+z^2=6y$ cut out by $x^2=36-6y$. First one is cylinder on x-axis wiht equation $(y-3)^2+z^2=9$ and the second is parabolic cylinder on z-axis.
Now not sure should I look $OYZ$ plane  and get bounds for circle using cylindrical coordinates, or I am on the wrong way?

Comment: I think you should look from top in the $z$-plane ($XY$) plane.

Comment: Yes, but in XY plane, I have parabola on x-axis(so dont have closed area).

Comment: Inverted parabola is on $y-$axis

Comment: Hahah, my bad :). Can i set then that $(y-3)^2=9-z^2$. And then $y=3+\sqrt{9-z^2}$(since this is XY plane this would be horizonatal lyne right?)

Comment: If you are in $XY$ plane, write $z = f(y)$. If in $XZ$ plane, then $y = f(z)$. But yes you can do either, $dx \, dz$ or $dx \, dy$.

Comment: Actually I missed that $x^2 = 36 - 6y \,$ leads to $-6 \sin \theta \leq x \leq 6 \sin \theta$. My bad. So it is easier to set up as $r = 6 \cos \theta$ so $y = 6 \cos^2 \theta, z = 6 \cos \theta \sin \theta, x$.  $r_x \times r_{\theta} = 6$.

Comment: I see typo in the above comment, I meant $|r_x \times r_\theta| = 6$.